# Usage of parenthesis in F#

Tags: f#

I am having an issue understanding the usage of parenthesis in F#. To illustrate with a simple example, the 2 following console apps behave very differently. The first one doesn't wait for me to type in anything:

```
open System
let Main =
   Console.WriteLine "Hello"
   Console.ReadLine
```

Whereas the second one does:

```
open System
let Main =
   Console.WriteLine "Hello"
   Console.ReadLine()
```

How should I understand the difference?

Comment: The same mistake is also in Main. It needs arguments, or else it is just a value. The reason it still runs, is that the value has to be evaluated, so it just happens to run, but it's still wrong to do it this way. Normally you'd have `args` as arguments, and return an int as exit code from the main function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a function takes no parameters, you specify the unit value () as the argument, as in the following line of code.

```
initializeApp()
```

The name of a function by itself is just a function value, so if you omit the parentheses that indicate the unit value, the function is merely referenced, not called.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx

That is why you have to do `Console.ReadLine()` rather than `Console.ReadLine` ( the latter returns a function delegate)

Comment: Note that you might as well read Console.ReadLine as being a function of one parameter which is of type unit (()).