# When to use parentheses when calling a function in f#?

Tags: f#

I'm learning about f# and I understand you don't need to use parentheses when calling a function.

Ex

```
let addOne arg1 =
    arg1 + 1

addOne 1
```

vs

```
this.GetType()
```

Why do I have to use parentheses on the second function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of parenthesis in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222759/usage-of-parenthesis-in-f)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a bit of a mismatch between working with .NET libraries and working with F# libraries when it comes to parameters, but you can generally see `()` not as parentheses, but as a special value of type `unit` that means "no useful information".

This means that when you say:

```
addOne 1
```

You are calling `addOne` with a value - number 1 - as a parameter. Now, when you apply the same reading to the second example:

```
this.GetType()
```

You can read this as calling `this.GetType` with a value - the special `()` unit value as a parameter. If you wanted to be consistent, you could write this with space too:

```
this.GetType ()
```

In practice, most people will omit the space when calling .NET libraries. When you do not write the space, F# also supports method chaining so you can write e.g. `foo().bar()`.

Many F# functions taking multiple parameters will use the "curried" form, which means that the parameters need to be separated by spaces. For example:

```
let add a b = a + b
let mul a b = a * b

add 10 (mul 20 3)
```

Here, you need parentheses around the second expression, so that the compiler knows how to parse the code. This is in contrast with typical .NET methods, which take parameters as a tuple. F# tuples are written as `(10, "hello")` and so you can see a method call as an ordinary call accepting a tuple:

```
some.Operation (10, "Hello")
```

Again, typically you wouldn't write the space here, because you know this is actually a .NET method call, rather than "passing tuple to a function", but conceptually, you can think of it in both ways.

This is the summary - there are a few corner cases where method calls do not really behave like tuples (e.g. when it comes to named parameters), but this way of thinking about it should give you an idea about how things work.

Comment: I only think of it as passing a tuple as argument, because not just conceptually but also technically that's what it is on the facade, in most cases. Only behind the scenes is it not. To demonstrate that, you can create the arguments - the tuple, that is - in a separate "let" statement, and then in the next step use the identifier for the tuple as argument to a function or method. I've found this pretty handy a few times, and definitely a trick you can't use in C#.

Comment: Tomas, this question is just the tip of the iceberg, or one leg of the elephant. Almost every newcomer stumbles on these issues, and fail to see the big picture. Somebody should write an article explaining about arguments, currying, tuples and unit - how it's all interconnected - and post it in a prominent place.

Comment: Yeah this is one place where my head is torn. I want to be consistent so want to write 'foo ()' but when using the .net libs i chain a lot and write 'obj.foo().bar()' rather than 'obj.foo ().bar ()'